# Check if active object has a modifier

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

How can I check if the *Active Object* has a specific modifier so that when I run my code, it doesn't add the modifier again to the object? It should add the modifier only to the object which does not use that modifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Check object for modifiers

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

if not obj.modifiers:
    print ("no modifiers")
else:
    print ("object has modifier(s)")
```

#### Check object for specific modifiers

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object

for modifier in obj.modifiers:
    if modifier.type == "SUBSURF":
        print ("subsurf")
```

For all types see: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Modifier.html?highlight=subsurf#bpy.types.Modifier.type

---

In your case I'd recommend using a **list comprehension** which returns `True` or `False`:

```
print(0 < len([m for m in bpy.context.object.modifiers if m.type == "SUBSURF"]))
```

or Python's [any()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any) plus the list comprehension.

```
print(any([m for m in bpy.context.object.modifiers if m.type == "SUBSURF"]))
```

---

#### Adding the *Modifier* if it isn't present

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
subsurf = obj.modifiers.new(name='MySubSurf', type='SUBSURF')
subsurf.levels = 2
subsurf.render_levels = 3
```

[image]