# How do I create a Multi-resolution mesh in Blender with Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to load tiled Lidar terrain data from here:

http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/#/survey

and stitch the tiles together.  The problem is the tiles are 1000 by 1000
samples and each mesh comes out as 1M vertices which bogs down the viewport.

Is there any way I can build a mesh with a Multires modifier and construct
the Subdivision levels in a Python script?  The API will let you check
if a mesh has a Multires modifier on it but I can't find a way to build one.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42080/check-if-active-object-has-a-modifier/42081#42081